# Change the link of a button based on a set of conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So basically I have this `sign up` button which when clicked on expands a hidden form.

What I want to be able to do is when the button is clicked the the first time, then the form should expand as it does at the moment, however I want it so that once the form is expanded, the same **button's link should change so the form could be submitted**.

As I have it at the moment when I click the button once the form has been expanded, it simply collapses the form back to how it was to start with.

Here is my code:

```
// jQuery Script that does the toggling for expanding and collapsing the hidden form
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-1").click(function(){
          $("#special1").toggle()
    })
})
</script>



//CSS rule for hiding the form (collapse)
<style>
    #special1{ display: none }
</style>



// HTML form
<center>
    <form action="form_process.php" id="special1">
    <div>

       <input type="text" class="input" name="forename" size="20" maxlength="40" placeholder="First Name"/> <br /> 
       <input type="text" class="input" name="surname" size="20" maxlength="40" placeholder="Surname"/> <br />
       <input type="email" class="input" name="email" size="20" maxlength="40" placeholder="Email"/> <br />
       <input type="password" class="input" name="password" size="20" maxlength="40" placeholder="Password"/> <br />
    <br/>


  </form>


  // This is the button that expands and collapses the above form
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="button-1" class="submit"/>

  </center>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the click event, check the visibility of the form and accordingly, display or submit it.
 
This should work -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-1").click(function(){
        if($("#special1").is(":visible")){
            $("#special1").submit();
        }else{
            $("#special1").show();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: (+1) I think this is the best solution provided because as you can see in the code the button is outside of the form element.

Answer (score 0):

You should unbind the click event after the first click.

```
$("#button-1").click(function(){
     $("body").off("click","#button-1");
      $("#special1").toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-1").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#special1").toggle()
    })
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-1").click(function(e){
          $("#special1").toggle();
          return false;
    })
});
```